# download attribute does not work in <a> tag

Tags: html, download

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and many posts, the tag

```
   <a href="..." download="..."></a>
```

must save a file, however for me it just opens an image in a browser: chrome, firefox, safari.

> download. Prompts the user to save the linked URL instead of navigating to it.

What should I do to force downloading to a drive, without JS?

Minimum working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/autumn-morning-at-the-cathedral-picture-id621235832?s=612x612" download="test.jpg">download </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: According to the documentation you gave : download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes. So if you are not hosting you page at istockphoto.com, it will not work ( 'Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified), and host are the same for both.).

Comment: Yup, I missed the notes. Probably they should change "the linked URL" to "the same-origin linked URL".

Answer (score 0):

This  [link](https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa) might be helpful . From Chrome 65+ download tag is discontinued. It is accepted only when it is from the same **origin**.

Problem here is, It uses JS. So, It is not completely independent of JS.

Comment: Seems like in pure html you can not do that. And this story works for safari and firefox as well.

Comment: Apparently , Because of CORS many browsers in their latest version are restricting it.